# Asynchronous Programming in node js to pass constants/predefined mandatory values through mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

I have multiple questions, please go through my code.

1) how to pass constants/predefined mandatory values through model?

For eg. I have some fields which user must be passing the values and some constants to pass on inside the kafkaSchema.config[ ] and also livySchema.args[ ]. The code i want to pass through is in second  question on the same question thread.

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const livy_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    file: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    className: { type: String, required: true },
    args: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }] //here i have constants to pass on to 
});

const kafka_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
    config: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true } //here i have constants to pass on to 
});


const enrichedEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    type: { type: String, enum: ["Enriched"], required: true },
    format: { type: String, enum: ["JSON", "DELIMITED", "FixedWidth", "LOG"], required: true },
    kafka: [kafka_schema],
    livy: [livy_schema]  // how to make this schema required:true?
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('EnrichedEvent', enrichedEventSchema);
```

2) how to make this code to run asynchronously, Right now its working synchronously. For example, Its able to save the eventdata in event collection in database, then its updating the project collection, then calling axios.post method to call my livy server and kafka server in order. What i want to do is save the eventdata in event collection in database, then update the project collection (synchronously), meanwhile I want to call my livy and kafka server at the same time (Asynchronously).

```
router.post("/:projectId/events/enriched", (req, res, next) => {
    const enrichedEvent = new EnrichedEvent({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        projectId: req.params.projectId, //taking from url
        description: req.body.description,
        type: req.body.type,
        format: req.body.format,
        kafka: req.body.kafka,
        livy: req.body.livy
    });
    enrichedEvent.save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.status(201).json({
                message: "Event stored",
                createdEvent: {
                    _id: result._id,
                    projectId: result.projectId,
                    name: result.name,
                    description: result.description,
                    type: result.type,
                    kafka: result.kafka,
                    livy: result.livy
                }
            });

            Project.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: result.projectId },
                { $push: { enrichedEvents: result._id } })
            axios.post("http://52.xxx.xxx.199:8998/batches", result.livy)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .then(axios.get("http://52.xxx.xxx.199:8998/batches/"), function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                })
            axios.post("http://52.xxx.xxx.199:8083/connectors", result.kafka)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({
                        error: err
                    });
                });
        });
});
```

Question may seem bit lengthy, but valid question to ask on SO. Please guide me to right direction.

Comment: Please break this into 2 separate questions with a more limited scope.  Your question is [too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267058/691711) as it is written right now.

Comment: @zero298 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871045/pass-a-hardcoded-value-through-mongoose-schema there you go buddy... and also upvote the question, coz... i m in a verge of getting banned from SO

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
const enrichedEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    // ...
    livy: { type: [livy_schema], required: true }
});
```

2)

```
return enrichedEvent.save().
  then(result => {
    // ...
    return Project.findOneAndUpdate(/*...*/);
  }).
  then(() => {
    // ...
    return Promise.all([axios.post(/*...*/), axios.post(/*...*/]);
  });
```

Comment: I didnt expected @vkarpov15 ll answer my question... actually the first question is all about can i pass some hard-coded values everytime when i m posting the data. I guess you have seen my comment in the code and answered it, which is also required for me.Anyway i ll edit the question.

Comment: the first question in this thread has been reposted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871045/pass-a-hardcoded-value-through-mongoose-schema

Comment: the first answer is not working,  livy: { type: [livy_schema], required: true }. Please provide an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hey try the following:

1) for saving user's entered configurations and also having default constants. You could use mongoose `pre save` hook.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

```
livy_schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.args = { ...this.args, ...CONSTANTS }; //I'm use es6's spread operator
  next();
});

kafka_schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.config = { ...this.config, ...CONSTANTS }; //I'm use es6's spread operator
  next();
});
```

2) For second question: try following:

```
axios.all([
  axios.post("http://52.221.178.199:8998/batches", result.livy),
  axios.post("http://52.221.178.199:8083/connectors", result.kafka)
]);
```

Comment: this is for question number two. Its working, could you please nswer for question 1.?

Comment: @darshanan I have updated my answer kindly see if this fix your problem.