# Pass a hardcoded value through mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to post some hard coded values along with user input(variables) every time.
`args: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }]` >>in this array i would like to pass some hard coded values along with user input variables.

Well my data to be posted looks like this.

`{"file": "**<user input>**","name":"<user input>", "className": "com.izac.Parser.IO", "args": ["-i", "{\"enrichedKafkaOptions\": {\"checkpointLocation\": \"**<hard coded path always remains the same>**", \"kafka.bootstrap.servers\": \"localhost:9092\", \"topic\": \"demoEnriched\"}, \"rejectedKafkaOptions\": {\"checkpointLocation\": \"/Users/vipulrajan/Desktop/checkpoints/DemoRejected\", \"kafka.bootstrap.servers\": \"localhost:9092\", \"topic\": \"demoRejected\"} }","-s", "{\"master\":\"local[*]\", \"appName\":\"app1\", \"config\":{\"jvm.memory\":\"4g\"} }"]};`

This is my schema,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const livy_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    file: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    className: { type: String, required: true },
    args: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }] //here i have constants to pass on to 
});

const kafka_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
    config: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true } //here i have constants to pass on to 
});


const enrichedEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    type: { type: String, enum: ["Enriched"], required: true },
    format: { type: String, enum: ["JSON", "DELIMITED", "FixedWidth", "LOG"], required: true },
    kafka: [kafka_schema],
    livy: [livy_schema]  
});
```

Original question [Asynchronous Programming in node js to pass constants/predefined mandatory values through mongoose model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51836461/asynchronous-programming-in-node-js-to-pass-constants-predefined-mandatory-value) .

I'm kind of in dilemma, like should i pass this hardcodeded values in router.post() method(if its possible, how should i code?) or in schema? please guide me in right direction.

Comment: You should modify the variable inside `router.post` to include the value you want

Comment: @Khang you are right I also thought the same, but the data i want to pass must be in order like: { filename: <userinput>,name<userinput>, location: <constant> , -i {name: <userinput>, order<constant>]...}

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: https://github.com/darshanan24/Farhan This is my git hub repository,Could you please look into the code. You ll get a overview. @Khang

Answer (score 1):

> Please excuse me if I am misunderstanding the question.

Since you are using mongoose schema you can have your field `default` be a function where you can initialize and add `hardcoded` values.

Something like this:

```
const livy_schema = mongoose.Schema({
      file: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      className: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      args: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
        required: true,
        default: function() {
          return { data: 'hardcoded!', info: 'hardcoded!' }
        }
      }] //here i have constants to pass on to 
    });
)
```

if the schema is in the right context I assume you can easily replace those strings with values being passed or swap the default function.

Comment: Hi, @akrion, you have absolutely understood my question, but actual data that i should be posting is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ex55xTBvKRsloLiLtenrc-c8ptiv3Cqvw4df9pDRVY0/edit?usp=sharing . Right now when i pass args data, which i hardcoded in code, giving me casting error. ValidationError: EnrichedEvent validation failed: livy: Cast to Array failed for value